# What is the relation of AIR BLEED IN message with the pack system on an Airbus A320?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a320, bleed-air

Before the power-up, if the pack switches are set to the ON position and the aircraft is powered up with the APU bleed off, is there a chance that the AIR BLEED IN maintenance message comes up on Lower ECAM page?

Comment: Could you please add which aircraft you are talking about? You mention **ECAM**, so probably an Airbus, but which one?

Comment: A320 neo and CEO @Bianfable

Answer (score 1):

On A320, if the BLEED P/B are still pushed ON, it will not be a reason from the FWC to get a an error message on the ECAM in phase 1, 2 or 10 (Elec power, 1st Eng Start and 2nd eng shutdown) But you definitely will have the FAULT in amber on the P/B itself until there is bleed from APU or Engine coming up.